# Is there a way to edit Langchain Agent's conversation as it is going on?

Tags: openai-api, langchain, large-language-model, py-langchain

I'm using langchain to query a MySQL database, but langchain agents always go over OpenAI's 4k token limit. When I looked into the agent's conversation history, it seems like the agent called `schema_sql_db` multiple times and the table schemas took up a lot of my tokens.

Is there a way for me to intervene and remove the schemas from my conversation histories, and also summarize the agent's history when it gets too long?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are a various ways to limit this token issue. I recommend you to use pinecone or weaviate databases if possible, but if not try using
Memory types- ConversationBufferMemory, ConversationSummaryMemory, ConversationBufferWindowMemory and there are more. Summerizing your content and you can make a separate emory class also.

For more information-[check out this python code](https://github.com/pinecone-io/examples/blob/master/generation/langchain/handbook/03-langchain-conversational-memory.ipynb)

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing this issue. However @Sam mentioned in my post that we can edit the sql_database.py agent from langchain library.

[Langchain's SQLDatabaseSequentialChain to query database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76525263/langchains-sqldatabasesequentialchain-to-query-database/76689058#76689058)

You can find the library in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\langchain` if you are in windows.

sql_databse.py is not the only file you may want to edit. I am also working on this and finding it difficult to perform.

Hope you find a solution